# Need some advice on personal program

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to learn how to code a program that will prompt a question, then display a list with a number and a corresponding string. example( 1 = Broken , 2 = Leaking, ect.) Then ask you to input the corresponding number and writes it to a .csv. So the .csv will contain the (Question, number, string)
Right now I have made a csv of numbers with strings about 99 cols long. I broke them down after loading the csv into pandas as a dataframe for specific questions example of one (dfr3 = df.iloc[[0,18,25,33], 1]). I'm kinda lost at this point I know how to call it sorta but that's as far as I got. I'm not 100% I'm going about this the right way.

```
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",encoding = 'unicode_escape', index_col = 0)
    dfq1 = df.iloc[[0,18,25,33], 1]
    question = input()

    if rule == 'Question1':
       print(dfq1)
```